# SSL on mail server

Tags: ssl, tls, email

A client of the company i work for asked if the email we provided them along with their domain will be SSL / TLS encrypted. We use qmail. What should I check to tell the client for sure that their e-mail communications are encrypted?

Comment: Does it require SSL? Did you look up the settings already?

Comment: I think that this is my problem. I don't know exaclty which settings to check. I typed this command


openssl s_client -connect remote.host:25 -starttls smtp

i found here 

http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cs-smtp

just to see if our mail server supports tls.

Judgong by the result i think it does.

Comment: sorry if posted on wrong place, i found a similar topic, asked it there, and was removed

Comment: @alfista16, what you did was asking a question in an answer box here on SO. You're meant to ask question as questions (which is what you've just done), but they're also meant to be on-topic for the site. Your question is typically more on-topic on ServerFault. You should be able to click on 'flag' and ask for a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are essentially two ways of using SSL/TLS for e-mail (SMTP, POP3, IMAP):

- implicit SSL/TLS, where the SSL/TLS connection is established first. This require a different port for each protocol: SMTPS, POP3S, IMAPS.
- explicit SSL/TLS, where a command is used to switch: `STARTTLS`.

Both should offer the same level of security, provided that they're configured correctly on both sides. The user would have to configure their client accordingly. As a service provider, you could consider providing both.

I don't know qmail very well, but it looks like it [requires a patch](http://www.memoryhole.net/qmail/#starttls), at least for STARTTLS support.

You can check whether either of them are enabled using `openssl s_client -connect host:port`, and (for the STARTTLS variants) use `-starttls` with the correct port (see `openssl s_client -help`).

You could also provide implicit SSL/TLS support by using an external tool like `stunnel` to be the SSL/TLS server (which would then make a localhost connection to the plain mail servers).